# How do I get past the lasers?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

In Detroit, there is a storage area behind a level 5 security lock.  Inside is a set of lasers guarding what looks like a bunch of stuff.  If I trigger the lasers, it sets off a deadly gas that will kill me within a few seconds.  How do I get past this part?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right behind those green barrels on the inside is the keypad for controlling the lasers.

Comment: as soon as I try to hack that keypad the gas is triggered, is this a bug?

Comment: I think it is a bug. I was able to get past it without getting gassed during my first visit to Detroit, but on the second (returning from another city-hub) it seemed bugged. If you have Praxis in cloaking, you can use cloaking to jump past the beams. You can also use an upgrade to be immune to gas.

Answer (score 4):

The switch is to your right. The keycode can be found the safe in Seurat's apartment, up the opposite fire escape.

If you like, the codes are:

> 1904 (door)
>  6542 (laser)

You can find a list of codes [here](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Keycodes_%28Deus_Ex:_Human_Revolution%29).

Comment: Good answer but...use codes instead of hacking? You lose all that juicy experience!

Comment: @jprete Which bugs me to no end, since you're essentially rewarded for sneaking around in the airducts, then going BACK to knock everyone out, finding all the codes and passwords, then rewarded for hacking the machines instead of using the codes.  Silly game designers and their rewards for extra (unnecessary) effort.

Answer (score 1):

There is just enough room to access the panel without hitting the laser if you stay right at the wall; either move the barrels or jump on them.

Otherwise:
Cloak and move heavy to get to the valve.
Rebreather so the gas doesn't bother you.